# TCP receiving last to first, I think

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have two programs both written in c# and one sends the following by using networkStream.beginWrite command:

> 1,2,3,4,5......200,201,202...(some termination byte array)

Now, I have the other program get the bytes and the first thing it reads for some reason is:

> 197, 198, 199....(termination array)

My question is, why is my TCP beginWrite sending it (the buffer) out of order?

Also, for some background information, I am reading it on the other side with beginReceive. Also, the byte array I am sending is 30000 bytes long and I am reading it into a 1024 byte buffer in the other computer. Would it be an issue if I do this and split it using the termination array?

Here is my send command on computer 1:

```
public bool sendToServer(SocketAsyncEventArgs e, params byte[][] buffer)
        {

            int length = 0;
            foreach (byte[] bytes in buffer)
            {

                length += bytes.Length;
            }
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte[length + 5];
            int index = 0;
            foreach (byte[] bytes in buffer)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, buffer2, index, bytes.Length);
                index += bytes.Length;
            }


            byte[] eof = { 60, 69, 79, 70, 62 };
            Buffer.BlockCopy(eof, 0, buffer2, index, 5);
           //  netStream.Write(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length);
             netStream.BeginWrite(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), clientSocket);
            //socketEventArg.SetBuffer(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length);
            //Socket sock = socketEventArg.UserToken as Socket;
            //bool willRaiseEvent = sock.SendAsync(socketEventArg);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + buffer2.Length + " bytes of data");
            //foreach (byte bi in buffer2)
            {
           //     Console.WriteLine(bi);
            }

         //   clientSocket.BeginSend(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length, 0,
          //      new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), clientSocket);


            return true;
        }
```

Here is my code to receive that data:

```
public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            // Get the socket that handles the client request.
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            // Create the state object.
            MonkeyObject state = new MonkeyObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            MonkeyObjects.Add(state);
            listener.BeginAccept(
                       new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                       listener);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            state.currentBuffer = buffer;  
            handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, MonkeyObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? What's a “termination array”?

Comment: At the end of the code, I append 5 bytes to it: 60,69,79,70,62

Comment: Would you like me to post the whole client and server project in a zip file? That would solve some of my other problems as well. This is a pretty simple thing that I am trying out.

Comment: Please post the smallest complete snippet of code that demonstrates the problem: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I know this is pretty extensive, but please see this if you wish: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1L3nHjvlFlUWXQ0eHp3OUJsbVk

Comment: You just need to change the DestAddr string in the client program to whatever your local ip is. Unless, there is a way to easily acquire that :)

Comment: You're not making it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason (as you show no code) is you are using same buffer for multiple send commands and they overwrite data that still should be send. In this case you may send semi-random data (depending when you update buffer and when actual send starts).

Comment: Okay, I will try to fix the buffer issue and see if that solves the problem. Will report back tomorrow

Comment: Note that my answer was posted before you posted whole bunch of code (with half of it commented out for some reason). It very well may not apply to your code.

Comment: I fixed it now by making computer 1 send the size of the data as well (so the computer2 knows how much to allocate for the buffer). I am not sure whether this is efficient. This is pretty much what I interpreted from your answer so Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the order of the packets on the network using a sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), just to be sure the code is doing what you think it's doing.

But TCP assigns a sequence number to each packet as it's sent, and the receiver uses the sequence numbers to reassemble the message in the proper order.  The packets don't need to *arrive* in the proper order, and in fact they sometimes don't.